# when trying to add a browsed picture an error message pops up but the code is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

this is my code:

```
if (this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
{
string destdir = Server.MapPath("./imgs/profileimgs");
string filename = Path.GetFileName(this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string destpath = Path.Combine(destdir, filename);
this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(destpath);
}
```

this error message is shown when i browse a picture on my computer and try adding it to the website:
" An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: לא היתה אפשרות לאתר חלק מהנתיב 'C:\Users\ST303\Desktop\Royals\GusetPages\imgs\profileimgs\gh.png'. "

side notes: C:\Users\ST303\Desktop\Royals\GusetPages\imgs\profileimgs\   is the root on my computer

Comment: Of all the great errors as a programmer, the statement `but the code is correct` has to be one of them.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of a command prompt clearly showing that it is in the folder `C:\Users\ST303\Desktop\Royals\GusetPages\imgs\profileimgs` (or `C:\Users\ST303\Desktop\Royals\GuestPages\imgs\profileimgs` which I suspect is the real folder name).

Answer (score 0):

'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' means Directory path is not found in computer which you have mentioned.

Try with another local drive path like "D:/Test/..." and checked that is working fine or not?

If the above solution is working and hence might be the problem of 'User rights in system drive'.